# Would it be possible, given current technology, ten years, and an infinite amount of money, to construct a 7,000 foot (2200 meter) aircraft carrier?

Tags: science-based, military, ships, shipbuilding

Given current technology, ten years, and an infinite amount of money, would it be possible to build an aircraft carrier with a 7,000-foot-long (2,200 meters) flight deck? This is about seven times as long as typical aircraft carriers. Catapults and other equipment are not required.

I'm tagging this as [military](/questions/tagged/military) because most if not all aircraft carriers are military ships, not because this will necessarily be used for military purposes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141222/discussion-on-question-by-someone-would-it-be-possible-given-current-technology).

Comment: An infinite amount of money is problematic.  I would rephrase it as "an indefinitely large supply of the resources money can buy".  Indefinitely large is better than infinite, and increasing the amount of money doesn't necessarily result in more purchasing power, especially as it rises without limit.

Comment: Related video: [Why don't aircraft carriers get bigger?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcEtgHPIFOs) (I randomly just watched this yesterday.)

Comment: The length:beam ratio of the USS Gerald R Ford is 8.  This means your ship would have to be **275 m wide**.

Comment: @RonJohn that means you can land three A380s side-by-side!

Comment: @WalterMitty I don't want to avoid supply chain issues, just funding. I can spend as much money as I want, but I still have to buy things.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Panama Canal” was my first thought, and “keep it in one ocean” was my second…

Comment: @Someone Can the performance be terrible? There's a huge difference between a 2km ship that's armoured, strong as an ox and moves at many knots, versus a horrendously slow and somewhat flimsy ship.

Comment: @SeanOConnor sure, as long as an A380 can land on it, it's fine if it's extremely slow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. [WillK wrote the basic concept](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/239174/9852): line up separate units, connect them together and put a runway over the whole. However, this poses huge problems if you use normal ships, because of the way they heave in the waves. Even in calm seas this is a considerable amount of motion (it's hardly perceptible for a human because it's so slow, but that's no help for a plane trying to roll from one ship to the next).

In principle it would be possible to connect the ships rigidly together to suppress this, but that would require infeasibly strong joints, because such big ships have enourmous leverage. Probably the hulls themselves would need to be strengthened too. Flexible joints would be more promising, since they avoid having to fight *all* the force of the waves – but making those reliable would be a challenge of itself, and it would cause other problems for the aircraft.

Fortunately, the situation if better if the individual units are [semi-submersible platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-submersible_platform): those generate most of their lift several metres below the surface, which means they're much less affected by waves.
Another advantage is that these platforms are already designed very heavy, since moving efficiency is much less of a concern than for military vessels. This means they're also less affected by the weight of the airliner. And oil companies already have a lot of experience in connecting such platforms together, so you'll be able to tap into that expertise.

The way I'd design this is like this: first create the runway as a relatively light *barge*, consisting of beams that are in the lengthwise direction only connected with thin-ish (like, 5 cm) steel plates and a tarmac layer. This way, the structure stays flexible enough so it doesn't need to fight the waves by itself – though of course it also wouldn't be able to support an airliner. Then, after towing it to deep enough waters, you rendezvous with the semi-submersibles, which would either dive underneath the runway to support it directly from below, or attach to the protruding beams on each side. It would possibly be best to make these connections still somewhat compliant, e.g. with air cylinders, but I'm not sure.

After making all the connections, you lift the runway above the level of the waves, either by pumping ballast out of the semi-submersibles, or increasing the piston pressure or with [strand jacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strand_jack). The end result is a runway that is supported strongly from the submerged lifting bodies, but with clearance in between so that the waves can harmlessly run underneath it – at least in calm waters. Whether this structure would be able to survive a storm on the open sea, I'm not sure about.

It would have a lot of similarity with a pontoon bridge. The largest such bridge, [Evergreen Point Floating Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evergreen_Point_Floating_Bridge), has almost exactly the dimensions you envision. It does benefit from crossing only a lake, not open sea – but I don't think that's completely necessary. E.g. [Nordhordlandsbrua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordhordland_Bridge) crosses a fjord: still not open-sea level waves, but they can already get pretty rough in bad weather.
Of course, these bridges are anchored to the sea bed, but sufficiently heavy semi-submersible bodies should get you close enough.

Comment: What kind of speed could one expect from one of these on open sea?

Comment: Don't know. Definitely much slower than a monolithic aircraft carrier.

Comment: left, you're 100% correct that semi-submersibles (ie: "oil rigs") are more stable than ships.  that's a fantastic point.  you're completely correct that, if this was to be done, it would without a doubt be done with semi-submersibles.  that's a great point.  HOWEVER unfortunately - although that point is completely true - we are no closer to an answer at all.  if an oil-rig-engineer came on here, he may well say "yeah there's zero chance of that, due to _ _ _ _".

Comment: Couldn't you use earthquake tech to help? The pistons that self balance to lessen the tremors.

Comment: I would like to point out an area that could be changed for strength. The runway part would need a lot of support from the submarines. Triangles are the strongest shape, and unfortified beams are easily broken. If you used 3-d triangles with angles of 45 degrees to make a base and covered the triangles with some form of flexible metal that can absorb some weight, this would provide enough strength without the submarines (but the submarines can be there just in case). As long as there is an even number of triangle layers, the triangles can form a strong surface. This will be lightweight.

Answer (score 27):

See [Project Habakkuk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Habakkuk)

That was to be 2000 feet long, which was huge for WW II. The aim was not to be as big as possible, but to be unsinkable. Torpedoes could knock lumps off it, but it could repair itself by mixing up and freezing more pykecrete. It could even be used for landings on coasts with cliffs, just by ramming the shore, and maybe leaving a few hundred feet behind when you were done.

There was no reason to make something 7000 feet long but it could be done.

You could even have a one-use device - omit the refrigeration unit, and build it somewhere cold in winter. Something that big would take a long while to melt.

Comment: Saw the title, immediately thought of this

Answer (score 13):

There are problems here which are difficult even with "infinite" money.

Landing an A380 on a minimal-length runway is not easy, especially since it will also be narrow compared to a normal runway. Landing it on a moving runway is going to be harder, since it lacks the responsive low-speed handling that is mandatory for carrier aircraft. The C-130 has been landed on a carrier, but it also has good low-speed handling, required for its role as a tactical military airlifter.

The A380's wingspan is 80 metres (261'8"), which sadly makes **HMS Conga** impractical; you're going to need 100 metres (330') width at a minimum. If something goes wrong during the braking after touchdown, the aircraft is very likely to end up in the sea: normal carrier aircraft are restrained by arresting gear, but this one won't be.

What is meant to happen to the aircraft once it has landed? If you unload and refuel it, you then need to tow it back to the stern of your carrier for it to have a chance of taking off successfully. If something goes wrong and it's immobilised on the deck, the carrier is out of action, and you may well have to push the aircraft over the side. That's harder and more dangerous for the ship with a 285-tonne (empty weight, metric tons and American long tons are very close) A380 than a 15-tonne Hornet or 19-tonne Hawkeye. This is one of the reasons the C-130 is not used for carrier deliveries: if it broke down, it would have to be discarded, since it's too big to be got out of the way of other aircraft.

Building a ship this long is not impossible but would be difficult and time-consuming. If it is built as a single rigid hull, it will have to be extremely wide and tall to avoid being bent by waves. If it's built in several articulated sections, prototyping the pivot mechanism in a smaller ship will be necessary to make sure it's strong enough. In either case, you need to build the world's largest dry dock to assemble the carrier in, which will be quite time-consuming.

Getting the ship built within ten years looks doubtful, and the use you want to put it to looks difficult and risky. Finding another way to achieve your desired outcome looks like a good idea.

Comment: Can you use metric units instead of imperial?

Comment: @VictorStafusa-FORABOZO: Done.

Comment: Good point about the time required to build the world's largest dry-dock.  That would have to be done first before much work could be done on the ship itself.

Comment: Landing on a moving runway is not a limiting factor. The net effect of something that large moving or not moving is simply perceived as wind. And why might it need to be narrower than a "normal" runway? If you can make something that long the width ought to be easy. Current supertankers are actually wider at around 225' than many major airport runways that tend to be around 200', and the A380 is actually certified to a minimum runway width of 150'

Answer (score 10):

From a standpoint of just making the ship longer, there's no particular limit. It's certainly possible to make a ship much longer than current maximum sizes.

The limitations are not directly on building the ship. There are other constraints and limits.

- The longer the harder to turn and the harder to stop.
- Canals and locks are difficult. For example, the Panama canal has a limit of about [965 feet.](https://www.aapa-ports.org/files/Panamax%20vs%20Post-Panamax%20comparison%20article.pdf)
- The longer the more structural strength must be built in to resist wave action and storm surge and such. This becomes prohibitive eventually, since you wind up with so much steel that it is hard to keep the thing afloat in anything but the calmest of conditions.

It would certainly be possible to join up a lot of individually modest floating structures. It would have to be a fairly robust join between the segments so that the weight of the plane did not depress a segment too much. As long as the water was not too rough, and you did not need this thing to be easy to move, you could build a surface that could be used as a runway. It would be something like a [pontoon bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontoon_bridge) but not anchored to the shore. You might have to split it up into segments in rough weather. And you might need a lot of tugboats to move it.

So such a thing would not be great in battle conditions. It might be useful as a temporary airport in a place with ocean but no good land area to build an airport. 7000 feet is at the [low end of jet aircraft runway length.](https://travelonthefly.com/minimum-runway-length-boeing-747/) Planes like a 747 with a heavy load will want more.

Comment: It will be used for an Airbus A380, which can land fully loaded on a 7000 foot runway. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/56990/how-long-does-a-runway-have-to-be-for-an-airbus-a380-to-takeoff

Comment: Are there any free (at least gratis and ideally libre)  "ship simulators" that could be used to get statistics on the maneuverability of such a ship?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to land an A380 in the middle of the ocean?

Comment: @Someone: About those statistics... How many ports can accept a 2.2 km long ship? You may want to look up, for example, the maximum [Chinamax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinamax) limits.

Comment: @AlexP  [Suezmax](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/Ship_measurements_comparison.svg/400px-Ship_measurements_comparison.svg.png) from the same page claims to allow unlimited length.

Comment: @Cadence no, there's no particular reason.

Comment: @candied_orange: Suezmax is not the specification for a port. Chinamax is.

Comment: @candied_orange: However, there's no way a ship this size will have a beam of only 77.5 metres. It won't fit through Suez, or any of the other size constraints.

Comment: @candied_orange You're either misunderstanding that image or whomever created it did a whomping bad job. The [Suezmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suezmax) naval architectual design has a maximum length of 400 meters. It gets its name from being the largest naval design that can transit the Suez canal. [Some supertankers are too large to traverse the canal.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suez_Canal#Capacity) Whatever that image means, the conclusion you're drawing is incorrect.

Comment: Can you use metric units instead of imperial?

Answer (score 6):

### No

It took eight years to build the USS Gerald R. Ford aircraft carrier ([Nov 2009 to May 2017](https://navalpost.com/why-does-an-aircraft-carrier-take-so-many-years-to-build/)). But that's not telling the whole story. It took [21 years](https://www.thefordclass.com/media/building-integrity-building-ford/) to start with a blank sheet of paper and end with a commissioned aircraft carrier. And the Gerald R. Ford is *only 1,106 feet long.*

Can you get 6.3X the ship with only 25% more time with today's tech? I'm having trouble believing that. The problem is that infinite money doesn't make all the other resources you need infinitely available. Ignoring completely the mind-bogglingly devestating effect this kind of event would have on any economy (even planetary), you can only get (e.g.) steel so fast. You can only transport so much at a time. You only have so much asphalt to work with. You only have so many trained people and you can only get a finite number more regardless the amount of cash you have.

It isn't just the effort needed to build the ship. it's the development of technologies needed to move it, power it, steer it, stabilize it, and a great deal more. Your question limited the answers to today's tech. When CVN-78 began, the technologies that allowed the ship to be built *didn't exist.* The technologies today to build a successful ship of the size you're describing *don't exist.*

And if that's not enough, there's feeding those people and their families. Educating their children and providing health care. It's *the entire supporting economy* that must be engaged. It's a nice theory to think that throwing money at it will fix all the problems, but that simply isn't true. I remember the world-wide steel availability problems that existed while China was building the Three Gorges dam. Your ship will cause problems like that, that can't be trivially solved with more money in the ten year period (now, if you had 20 years before the ten year period to prepare for this and the many other problems... maybe... *maybe...* there isn't a shipyard on the planet today that can build a ship this long).

So, ignoring all the problems of having an ultra-long aircraft carrier (and those answers haven't even scratched the surface of the problems), no, I do not believe it's realistically possible to crank out a 7,000 foot aircraft carrier with today's tech. Money isn't the limiting resource. In fact, there isn't one limiting resource.

*And if you start making concessions (e.g., "Let's assume the 13 years of technical planning are already in place...") then there isn't a reason to ask the question.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141276/discussion-on-answer-by-jbh-would-it-be-possible-given-current-technology-ten).

Answer (score 5):

- **Timeline problems:**
  Some others mentioned that it cannot be done, citing the design times of real-world aircraft carriers and other similar projects. I have a slightly different take on that, or maybe a counter-question: Are we talking about a wartime/crisis project, or "just" infinite money?
  Is it acceptable to build the first prototype in three or four years, to watch where cracks develop when it floats, and to do a second and a third prototype? Can environmental impact assessments for the drydock site be skipped?
- **Structural problems:**
  These might become more serious than some other answers seem to think. Normally, naval architects worry about [hogging and sagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogging_and_sagging), the stresses when the ends or the middle of a ship are on a wave crest. These are worst when the wave length equals the length of the ship. This might be less of a problem than usual, if significant waves are much shorter than the ship. But similar calculations would need to be made e.g. for situations where the ship passes a river mouth, or where part is within an ocean current and part outside. That could be much harder to predict and design for since stresses are more random.

Answer (score 4):

**Line them up.**

[image: conga]

https://www.navylookout.com/what-are-they-for/

Depicted: the HMS Conga.  You can make a superlong flight deck by lining up a bunch of your existing aircraft carriers.  And you should.

I will accept my 1% share of the infinite amount of money, thank you.

Comment: Could they be lined up precisely enough to form one long runway?

Comment: @Someone:  you would want calm seas.

Comment: Would it be possible to make this work in not-really-calm-but-not-a-storm-either seas?

Comment: @Someone I'm not entirely sure you could even manage it on Salt Lake, let alone an ocean. What happens when there's a 2.5 inch difference in altitude between two of them before the landing gear is retracted? Do they just feel a bump, or does it tear the wheel off?

Comment: @JohnO that ship is of the [Queen Elizabeth Class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Elizabeth-class_aircraft_carrier) with the [Ski Jump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ski-jump_(aviation)) configuration. So there's a bit more than a 2.5 inch altitude difference.

Comment: They'd have to not only be lined up, but in physical contact and level with each other. If there's a one foot gap between two of the ships, the landing gear are just going to fall into it. If one ship is a few inches higher than the previous in line, you're going to run into it. The ships would all have to be rigidly locked together, which would bring back most of the problems of a 7000 foot ship.

Comment: I am pondering a system where 2 adjoining ships are rigidly locked together only for the couple of seconds before the plane crosses from one to the next.  The rigid lockers detects the plane coming and locks the runway for those 2 seconds then relaxes back into a flexible connection.

Comment: @Jay Can you use metric units instead of imperial?

Comment: @VictorStafusa-FORABOZO - Jay might be constrained by the types of ship available in this fictional world.  Maybe none of them are metric unit ships.

Comment: @Willk Interesting idea. It brings numerous technical problems to mind, but then the question becomes whether these are more or less than the problems of a 2200 meter ship (there, I used metric). Before the lock, the ships would have to be close enough together and in the right position for the locking mechanism, however it works, to pull them together and lock them within 2 seconds, and then release them. And while the two ships are that close together, they would have to avoid colliding and damaging each other. ...

Comment: ...  I don't know of any present technology to do that, so I could quibble that the question said "present technology". But whether such a gadget is a reasonably plausible extension of present technology ... I don't know. I don't know how I would go about building such a device, but of course there's a huge difference between "I don't know how to do it" and "it can't be done".

Comment: this doesn't work at all, water moves

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to make a lot of smaller ships which had big flat sections in their middle between any forecastles and sterncastles they might have.  They would have flight decks in the flat sections.  And more flight deck on each side in the form of drawbridges which could raised or lowered.

So in calm weather the ships could all be in formation parallel to each other and lower their drawbridges to meet each other to form a long runway. Presumably drones could carry cables from the tip of one drawbridge and insert them into the tip of the neighboring drawbridge, which would then winch them closer and closer until they met.

Or possibly the sections of the flight deck for use betwen the ships would be carried folded up when the ships were separated and would unfold to meet the neighboring ships when they were connecting.

Or possibly the ship would be assembled out of many floating rectangular sections which would launched separately and then meet previously launched sections and attach to them.

Each section of flight deck, hanger deck, and other decks, might be supported above the ocean by several shafts leading to hollow watertight floats. And possibly the shafts might have sections which could slide up and down relative to each other as the waves lifted up the floats and lowered them again, keeping the flight deck level.  And possibly the floats might turn like giant paddle wheels to propel the giant aircraft carrier.

You could reduce the length of runway needed for takeoffs by using JATO units.

> JATO (acronym for jet-assisted take-off) is a type of assisted take-off for helping overloaded aircraft into the air by providing additional thrust in the form of small rockets. The term JATO is used interchangeably with the (more specific) term RATO, for rocket-assisted take-off (or, in RAF parlance, RATOG, for rocket-assisted take-off gear).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JATO

Forward facing JATO units have sometimes been used to slow down landing aircraft.

So possibly extensive use of JATO could enable your giant aircraft carrier to be a bit shorter than it would otherwise need to be.

Of coure the best way to shorten needed runway lengths would be to only use vertical take off and landing aircraft.

Comment: Perhaps, "what would it take to build a VTOL A-380" could be a follow-up question here?

Answer (score 3):

### No, probably

Folks seem to generally discount the fact that stuff like this requires planning, and planning takes time.

Consider the history of the A380:

- 1988: initial germ of idea
- 1990: project announced
- 1992: initial designs presented
- 2000: Airbus commits to construction
- 2005: first test flight

Granted, the A380 faced numerous random hurdles, including coordination problems among half-a-dozen Eurozone partners, org changes at Airbus, and an economic recession. **Unless your project takes place in a fictional society of perfect beings, it will face its own unique, *stupid* hurdles, all of which will slow it down.**

Blueprints take time to design. People who design things aren't just drawing lines on paper -- they are thinking through problems, solving them, and then capturing *part* of the solution as a physical description of the construct.

Or consider the the latest US aircraft carrier, the "Gerald R Ford" class:

- 2008: procured
- 2017: first commissioned

If your goal were a marginal increase over previous versions, my answer would be "yes": creating an aircraft carrier that's 5% bigger probably isn't much harder, so existing techniques will work, and we can assume this project will run similar to previous projects: just under a decade.

But you're not making a marginal increase. You're building something roughly seven times bigger. This will inevitably run into new problems. It will require vastly more planning, vastly more money, and vastly more time.

I doubt it could be done in under 25 years, and that's assuming an ironclad guarantee, evident from the beginning, that all necessary funding and materials will be available *on time.*

Skynet could probably do it. Independent organic beings could not, at least not the first time.

Oh, and the physics is hard, so it might actually be practically impossible. Other answers go into that in detail.

Comment: There's a big difference between: designing a product that needs to be as safe as an airliner, optimised to be able to compete with existing jets, and do it all on a budget that makes it economically viable, and: designing something novel that needs to do a certain job, where it's ok if a lot of money and perhaps even human lives are lost in the process. Obvious examples include the US nuclear bomb (Manhattan Project) and Apollo missions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, the Apollo missions are a perfect counter to the naysayers.  If we could put people on the moon inside of a decade we could certainly build a carrier of sorts that's quite a bit shorter than typical land runways.  (providing we let go of the paradigm that it has to look and perform like a "traditional" Navy aircraft carrier...)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to make a concrete boat.

If we are trying to make a sea-going platform that does not have to defend itself, I feel it could be done in the time. You are not trying to make a capital ship that could survive any attack, but a big,box that floats, and can move itself or be towed.

The Phoenix caissons that made the Mulberry harbours for the D-Day landings were 60x20 metres, and over 200 were produced in a year or so. They were made to be grounded, rather than being fastened together at sea, but this would have been possible. Fasten 40x5 of these together and you would have something 2400 * 100 meters, and 15 meters high.

This is five times as long as the largest ship ever.